# ios: Trash Locale for "fr" identifier

Tags: ios, swift

Any idea why Locale(identifier: "fr") vends a locale with currencyCode == nil and how to work around that?

```
        if countryCode.count >= 5 {
            self.countryCode = countryCode
            locale = Locale(identifier: countryCode)
        } else {
            self.countryCode = countryCode.lowercased()
            locale = Locale(identifier: self.countryCode!)
        }
        if locale?.currencyCode == nil {
            locale = nil
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this trips for incoming countryCode "fr"!
        }
```

meaning Locale(identifier: "fr") creates non nil Locale object
where currencyCode is nil

> (lldb) po locale!.currencyCode nil
>
> (lldb) po locale ▿ Optional   ▿ some : fr (fixed)
>       - identifier : "fr"
>       - kind : "fixed"

The goal is to get Locale with a currencyCode other than nil

Comment: French is spoken in many countries! For `"fr_FR"`  you'll get "EUR", for `"fr_VU"` you'll get "VUV" (Vanuatu vatu)

Comment: The locale `fr` is just a language. There's no country info. French is spoken in many countries using different currencies. So it's not clear what result you expect.

Comment: It shows up here             let codes = Locale.availableIdentifiers;
            print ("\(codes)")

Comment: and indeed fr_FR yields a valid Locale object. Thank you.

Comment: If you are iterating `availableIdentifiers` but you want to ensure you get a currency code, skip any identifier that is only a language code. And your `countryCode` variable doesn't actually represent a country code.

Comment: ok, so anything without underscore should be dumped on the floor. Thanks. So between the two of you maybe write up an answer if you think this question will help anyone?

Comment: The problem with your question is that your goal isn't clear enough to write a proper answer. I suggest explaining what you are actually trying to accomplish ([edit] your question) and include the issues you are having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181267/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-rmaddy).

Comment: As well the "en" locale will return a nil currency, unlike "en_US", "en_CA", "en_GB", "en_ZA", "en_IN", "en_IE", "en_NZ", "en_AU"... which all have a different non-nil currency.
Locales for languages only do not necessarily have currency info. In fact all locales with just a code for a language should return a nil currency, even "ru" (don't assume this is in Russia), or "ja" (don't assume this is in Japan), or "it" (don't assume this is in Italy): languages are now used in many more countries than their origin, even if most of its speakers are in a single country.

Comment: And you could be surprised that "en_EU" is a valid locale for English, but that it still does not have any currency info (hint: "EU" is a code for the European Union, not all Europe as for the Council of Europe members, but the EU is still using multiple currencies, including EUR, SEK, DAK, GBP, and even the USD for some remote overseas of its members).

Comment: As well don't assume that even a single country has a single currency (e.g. France uses Euro and CFP Franc) or a single language (e.g. Belgium uses "fr", "nl", "de", and culturally "wa", "vls", "li"). You need to allow locales to be customized for the country, or currency; locale identifiers can be more complex than just "languagecode_countrycode": see BCP 47 for info, and look at Unicode locale codes that have multiple fields.

Comment: verdy_p:  you could just as well dump this into an answer that will be promptly upvoted and accepted. thank you.